# java tests using jacoco

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

I have a folder with tests for the project (src/test/java/com.example.carsharing). There are currently 5 test classes. And one of them just throws an error (AuthServiceTest). All other of them work properly. What should I do to fix this error?

error text

```
Execution failed for task ':test'.
No tests found for given includes: [com.example.carsharing.AuthServiceTest](--tests filter)

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestExecutionException: No tests found for given includes: [com.example.carsharing.AuthServiceTest](--tests filter)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.handleCollectedResults(AbstractTestTask.java:485)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.executeTests(AbstractTestTask.java:478)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:690)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor602.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 452ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Also, I'll provide the code of the test class that throws the error `AuthServiceTest`

```
package com.example.carsharing;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import com.example.carsharing.Auth.AuthService;
import com.example.carsharing.Auth.UserJwtPayload;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.util.Date;


public class AuthServiceTest {
    private AuthService authService;
    private Algorithm algorithm;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("Somesecretkeyherenothingweryinterestingthough");
        authService = new AuthService();
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithValidToken() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", 123)
                .withClaim("email", "test@example.com")
                .sign(algorithm);

        UserJwtPayload payload = authService.verifyUser(token);

        assertEquals(123, payload.id);
        assertEquals("test@example.com", payload.email);
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithInvalidToken() {
        String token = "invalidToken";
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }
    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithTokenMissingRequiredClaims() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create().sign(algorithm);
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithInvalidDataTypes() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", "invalidId") // id should be a long
                .withClaim("email", 123) // email should be a string
                .sign(algorithm);

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }
    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithEmptyClaims() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", "")
                .withClaim("email", "")
                .sign(algorithm);

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }
    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithIncorrectSecret() throws Exception {
        // Create a token with a different secret
        Algorithm wrongAlgorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("wrongSecret");
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", 123)
                .withClaim("email", "test@example.com")
                .sign(wrongAlgorithm);

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithAdditionalClaims() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", 123)
                .withClaim("email", "test@example.com")
                .withClaim("extra", "extraData") // extra claim
                .sign(algorithm);

        UserJwtPayload payload = authService.verifyUser(token);

        assertEquals(123, payload.id);
        assertEquals("test@example.com", payload.email);
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithExpiredToken() throws Exception {
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", 123)
                .withClaim("email", "test@example.com")
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000)) // expired 10 seconds ago
                .sign(algorithm);

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithTokenSignedWithDifferentSecret() throws Exception {
        Algorithm differentAlgorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("differentSecret");
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("id", 123)
                .withClaim("email", "test@example.com")
                .sign(differentAlgorithm);

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }

    @Test
    void testVerifyUserWithMalformedToken() {
        String token = "this.is.not.a.valid.token";
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> authService.verifyUser(token));
    }


}
```

When I tried to move this test (AuthServiceTest) outside the com.example.carsharing package, all the tests worked fine, but when the jacoco report was generated, it just didn't see this test.
Also, I tried renaming the class in the file. ie the name of the file was AuthServiceTest and the name of the class in the file was AuthServiceTestt , it also worked but no report was generated for this test

Comment: That `AuthServiceTest` is using JUnit 5 (as indicated by the `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`). Are the other tests also JUnit 5 tests or are they JUnit 4 tests (that would be indicated by an `import org.junit.Test;` in those files)? Did you configure you build script to run JUnit 5 tests (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5)?

Comment: No, all tests are on JUnit 5 (org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;)

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be a  configuration of your jacoco-maven-plugin. Take a look at this example.

```
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>edu/example/**/*Service*</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

It configures jacoco only include classes mathing a pattern in the report. In this case it includes all classes that have full name `edu.example.*.*Service*` or, in other words, any classes inside `edu.example` package that have `Service` in their name.

Check your `pom.xml` if it includes the class you need.